# What did C-3PO say in a foreign language?

Tags: star-wars, the-rise-of-skywalker

I didn't hear this clearly when I went to see *The Rise of Skywalker*, but...

**What did C-3PO say in the Sith language?**

The best I could find online is:

> So of course, C-3PO courageously sacrifices his memories to save his friends, and for a second his eyes gleam bright red -- as seen in the trailers -- as he recites the coordinates of Exegol and the Sith Fleet.
>   <sub>[Star Wars: C-3PO’s Biggest Limitation in Rise of Skywalker Makes NO Sense](https://www.cbr.com/star-wars-rise-of-skywalker-c3po-sith-block/)</sub>

I'm even more confused, since I thought we needed the [Sith wayfinder](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Sith_wayfinder) to get to Exegol, and not just "directions":

> C-3PO: Oh, I read it, sir. I know exactly where the wayfinder is. Unfortunately, it is written in the runic language of the Sith.
>   <sub>[Star Wars: The Rise of Skywalker Best Quotes – ‘No one’s ever really gone.’](https://www.moviequotesandmore.com/star-wars-the-rise-of-skywalker-best-quotes/)</sub>

Comment: Just as an aside, I think C-3PO probably said "runic language of the Sith". :-)  And, yeah, I think whoever wrote that first article hadn't understood the plot, C-3PO was indeed directing them to the wayfinder (i.e., the ruins of the Death Star) not to Exegol.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

C-3PO isn't giving them the directions to Exegol, he says that they can find another Wayfinder at the site of the crashed Death Star II.

> *"The Emperor's Wayfinder is in the Imperial Vault. At Delta 3 6, Transient 9 3 6, Bearing 3 2, on a moon in the Endor System. From the Southern shore, only this blade tells".*

The Emperor's Wayfinder will then give them the directions and transit points to get to Exegol.

Answer (score 6):

What C-3PO read on the blade was where to find the Wayfinder, not directions to Exegol.
He recites instructions where to find the Wayfinder including if I remember correctly that it is a vault in the Emporer's throne room on the remains of the Death Star.

Comment: Right. Valorum's answer is technically correct, but this one is more pertinent as to why the OP is confused; namely, what was written at CBR is wrong.

Comment: @Matthew - well Valorum obvz got the exact quote in so totally deserves to get his answer accepted.